# Type declaration error: [Char] and [[Char]]

Tags: haskell

With the below snippet I want to append/prepend a string to a list that is part of a value stored in a map.

From the snippet below I get the error

```
Couldn't match expected type `Char' with actual type `[Char]'
    Expected type: Map.Map ([Char], Integer) [Char]
      Actual type: Map.Map ([Char], Integer) [[Char]]
```

and I am not quite sure what that should tell me. Can that be solved with a change in the code or must there be something like

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
```

Together with an instance declaration?

```
import Data.Time
import Data.Time.Clock.POSIX
import qualified Data.PSQueue as PSQ
import qualified Data.Map as Map
import Data.Maybe
import Control.Category
import Control.Concurrent
import Control.Concurrent.MVar
import Control.Monad

key = ("192.168.1.1", 4711)
messages = ["aaa", "bbbb", "ccccc"]

newRq = do
      time <- getPOSIXTime
      let q = PSQ.singleton key time
      let m = Map.singleton key messages
      return (q, m)

appendMsg :: String -> (String, Integer) -> Map.Map ([Char], Integer) [Char] -> Map.Map ([Char], Integer) [Char]
appendMsg  a (b, c) m = m2
      where 
          f x = x ++ a
          m2 = Map.adjust f (b, c) m

main :: IO()
main = do
     (q, m) <- newRq
     let m2 = appendMsg "first" key m
     print (m2)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a change in the code. You start with a `Map (String, Integer) [String]`, by creating a singleton with value `messages`. Your update function however is written for `Map (String, Integer) String`. Either change it to the appropriate type by making it `f x = x ++ [a]` (and change the type signature to

```
appendMsg :: String -> (String, Integer) -> Map (String, Integer) [String]
                                         -> Map (String, Integer) [String]
```

too) or change your initial map by using e.g. `unwords messages`. (I think you'll rather want the first.)

Comment: Tried that already. However, then I get an error saying `No instance for (IsString Char)
      arising from the literal `"ccccc"`. Adding `import Data.String` does not help either.

Comment: Forgot to mention, you have to change the type declaration of `appendMsg` to use `Map (String, Integer) [String]` too.

Comment: Thanks! Is by the way a [String] not a [Char]?

Comment: No, a `String` is a `[Char]`, so a `[String]` is a `[[Char]]`. You could of course replace all `String`s in the signature with `[Char]`, but I find it helpful to distinguish between `String` for meaningful text and `[Char]` for arbitrary lists of `Char`, e.g. `vowels :: [Char]`.

Answer (score 2):

`[Char]` and String are the same type.  The Haskell prelude has the following type synonym definition:

```
type String = [Char]
```

... which basically means those two types mean the exact same thing and are completely interchangeable.  This means we can rewrite the compiler error as:

```
Expected type: Map (String, Integer) String
  Actual type: Map (String, Integer) [String]
```

The two type parameters of the `Map` type are its `Key` type and its `Value` type.  So if you have a `Map Int String` type, that means it's a map with `Int`s as keys and `Strings` as values.  This means you can now interpret the compiler message a little more clearly:

```
Expected type: Map from keys of type "(String, Integer)" to values of type "String"
  Actual type: Map from keys of type "(String, Integer)" to values of type "[String]"
```

This tells us that somewhere in your code you gave it a map where every value is a `[String]` (i.e. a **list of strings**), but it was expecting a map where every value was just a single `String`.  In fact, you can trace the error to this line of code:

```
let m = Map.singleton key messages
```

`messages` is, you guessed it, an list of `String`s (i.e. `[String]`), and you told it to store the entire array `messages` as a single element in the map `m` when you used the `singleton` function to initialize it.  So Haskell correctly inferred the value type of `m` had to be `[String]` (which was obviously not what you intended).

The compiler then noticed something was amiss when you tried to append a string to every element in your map in the following line:

```
let m2 = appendMsg "first" key m
```

You told the compiler "Please concatenate this string onto every element of my map" and the compiler then tells you "But you don't have multiple strings stored in your map; You have just one list of strings stored as a single value in your map, so I can't append 'first' onto the array itself".

The fix is simple where instead of using `singleton` to initialize `m`, you just `fromList`, which takes a list of elements (i.e. `messages`) and converts each element in the list to an element of the map, which is what you intended.

Comment: "(i.e. an array of strings)", I suppose you know the difference and just were a bit off guard, but it's important to keep the difference between lists and arrays to avoid confusing newbies. Trying to treat lists as arrays is a common mistake leading to frustration.

Answer (score 1):

The map you're creating with `Map.singleton key messages` is a `Map.Map (String, Integer) [String]`. However your declaration of `appendMsg` indicates that you really want a `Map.Map (String, Integer) String`. You need to revisit your `newRq` and figure out what you're really trying to do with that `Map.singleton` line.